# nginx: using directives with if

Tags: nginx

I want to have the logical:

```
if ($do_not_cache) {
fastcgi_pass_header "Set-Cookie";
}
```

But I got error: "fastcgi_pass_header" directive is not allowed here

I tried to use named locations for "fastcgi_pass_header "Set-Cookie"" but don't know, how to forward in it in if section.

I tried to forward in location with this construction:

```
if ($do_not_cache = 1) {
rewrite ^(.*(?<!nginx_cache))/$ https://$server_name$1?r=no_ cache permanent;
}
```

but it doesn't work properly too.